# CALLING AN EXTERNAL HTML PAGE THROUGH InnerHTML (with out ajax or iframe)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//something like this index.html should be in like pop up

document.getElementById('pop_up_main').innerHTML = 'index.html';
```

Comment: Pretty sure this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Is it possible to use iframe - <iframe src="link.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

Comment: @RRR — The question title explicitly rules out iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property takes a *string of HTML*.

It doesn't take a URL. It has no mechanisms for getting data from external sources (except insofar that you can set its value to some HTML which will do that: e.g. an `iframe` which you've already ruled out).

If you want to get content from a URL to assign to `innerHTML` then you need to make an HTTP request to do it. Unless you are doing that with server-side code and storing the data somewhere in the HTML document itself (e.g. in a `data-*` attribute) then you have to make that HTTP request with JavaScript … and that is the definition of Ajax (which you've ruled out).

Comment: sure sir this was to help full !